# The LogoutAsync() method not found in the MobileServiceClient

Tags: azure, xamarin

In Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices namespace, the class MobileServiceClient is supposed to have a LogoutAsync method according to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient(v=azure.10).aspx). But it does not have such method.

Comment: Are you just starting on a new project? If so, please do note that the [Azure Mobile Services](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/) package is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. `LogoutAsync()` does not exist in the namespace anymore. This is most likely due to the fact that the package was deprecated as mentioned in this [announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/blog/transition-of-azure-mobile-services/). Conclusively, I wouldn't rely on the documentation being updated. Instead, you should consider using Azure App Service instead.

That said, a method does exist for [logging a user out](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/9b9efcafc8aacfbd3aaaf777105ee1251853480b/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/MobileServiceClient.cs#L368) in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices` namespace. Although, all it does is setting the `CurrentUser` to `null`.